# Restarting apache with Jenkins or Phing

Tags: apache, codeigniter, continuous-integration, hudson, phing

I'm currently using Phing and Jenkins to automate builds and deployment for my CodeIgniter app. One problem I'm having trouble with is restarting the apache service. I tried in Phing but there isn't enough permissions. What is the best way to restart?

**EDIT:**

After adding jenkins into the sudoer file and exec'ing the service httpd restart, Jenkins throws: Process leaked file descriptors. Below is a snippet of the Phing output via Jenkins. It says a workaround is to install daemonize. Not sure what that means...

```
...Build_test > compress:

     [echo] YUI Compression started
     [echo] Replacing normal JS with compressed files.
     [echo] Replacing normal CSS with compressed files.
     [echo] chmoding assets
     [echo] YUI Compression ended

Build_test > pdepend:


Build_test > httpd_restart:

     [echo] Stopping httpd: [  OK  ]
     [echo] Starting httpd: [  OK  ]


BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 13.1424 seconds

Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Found 68 classes in 1 packages
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: There is an issue with spawning new process in Jenkins. I guess restarting apache falls into this category as a new process id will be created. Have you tried adding the restart to a post-build task? I'm just wondering why you are restarting Apache after doing compression and phpdepend tasks anyway? Are you rebuilding vhost configs or something as well?

Comment: I'm using APC. If I don't restart, sometimes I get a white screen of death. If you know a way around that problem with APC, let me know :) But do they have a plugin for restarting apache as a post-build task?

Comment: I actually just found the plugin, thanks for the tip! But if I can get a fix for the white screen of death problem without restarting apache, that would be great!

Comment: Never come across that APC issue but I'd look into it and try and fix it rather than code around it with apache restarts. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on Linux you can run Phing with the sudo command to allow it enough privileges to restart apache.

```
sudo phing restartapache
```

Assuming that restartapache is an exec task that calls the apache restart command. Eg:

```
<target name="restartapache" description="Restarts the web server">
    <exec command="/etc/init.d/apache2 restart" />
</target>
```

To avoid the sudo command prompting for a password you can update your sudo permissions for whatever user account you are running your build under (this example demonstrates turning off the sudo password prompt for the jenkins user):

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add the following lines:

```
Defaults:jenkins !requiretty,!lecture
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/apache2
```

The above has been edited to improve security according to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26101/restarting-nginx-with-jenkins-or-phing-is-it-safe-to-allow-jenkins-to-run-sudo/26267#26267) so that Jenkins is only allowed to restart apache without a password and nothing else.

Comment: got it working with some exceptions. Take a look at the description for the new info.

Comment: Granting blanket permission for jenkins to run *anything* is a bad idea. See [this answer here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/26267/2264) for how to improve your solution.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer with your improved solution.