# How can I use ant <exec> to execute commands on linux?

Tags: java, linux, ant

I would like to use ant  to exectue a command like below:

```
<exec executable="echo ptc@123 | sudo -S /app/Windchill_10.0/Apache/bin/apachectl -k stop">
</exec>
```

But it replies an error say

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are not part of the command.

The background is: I want to use ant to stop the apache server but it doesn't installed by the same user I run the command.

Anyone could help or give me some clues?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28):

Ant's `<exec>` task uses Java's `Process` mechanism to run commands, and this does not understand shell-specific syntax like pipes and redirections.  If you *need* to use pipes then you have to run a shell explicitly by saying something like

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh">
  <arg value="-c" />
  <arg value="echo ptc@123 | sudo -S /app/Windchill_10.0/Apache/bin/apachectl -k stop" />
</exec>
```

but in this case it's not necessary, as you can run just the `sudo` command and use `inputstring` to provide its input rather than using a piped `echo`:

```
<exec executable="sudo" inputstring="ptc@123&#10;">
  <arg line="-S /app/Windchill_10.0/Apache/bin/apachectl -k stop" />
</exec>
```

Since `sudo -S` requires a newline character to terminate the password, I've added `&#10;` on the end of the `inputstring` (this is the simplest way to encode a newline character in an attribute value in XML).

Note that `<arg line="..." />` is pretty simple minded when it comes to word splitting - if any of the command line arguments could contain spaces (for example if you need to refer to a file under a directory such as `${user.home}/Library/Application Support` or if the value is read from an external `.properties` file that you don't control) then you must split the arguments up yourself using separate `arg` elements with `value` or `file` attributes, e.g.:

```
<exec executable="sudo" inputstring="ptc@123&#10;">
  <arg value="-S" />
  <arg file="${windchill.install.path}/Apache/bin/apachectl" />
  <arg value="-k" />
  <arg value="stop" />
</exec>
```

Comment: There's a technique to add Jenkins to sudoers so you don't have to persist the root password http://stackoverflow.com/a/6897382/389976