# Unable to upload a file using curl with target in build.xml

Tags: curl, ant

I am successfully able to upload data using the following curl command.

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -T abc.json https://myURL
```

However, when I try to do the same using a build target in build.xml using the following statements, no data is ever uploaded.

```
<target name="upload-to-MY-URL">
          <exec executable="curl">
              <arg value="-k" />
              <arg value="-H" />
              <arg value="Content-Type: application/json" />
              <arg value="-X PUT" />
              <arg value="-T" />
              <arg value="abc.json" />
              <arg value="https://myURL" />
          </exec>
      </target>
```

I receive the following output but no uploaded data on the URL.

```
    upload-to-MY-URL:
     [exec]   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
     [exec]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     [exec] 
     [exec]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0  8699    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
BUILD SUCCEEDED
```

Is there something I could do with respect to changing the arguments to make it work?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use ant <exec> to execute commands on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883212/how-can-i-use-ant-exec-to-execute-commands-on-linux)

Comment: It doesn't @Andrei Kovrov My execution is successful but does not lead to the desired output.

Comment: You could also add `-v` for `curl` to understand what happens for your ant script and just shell command and then compare.

Comment: I just separated -X and PUT and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the fix was simple. Separated values -X and PUT as follows.

```
<target name="upload-to-MY-URL">
      <exec executable="curl">
          <arg value="-k" />
          <arg value="-H" />
          <arg value="Content-Type: application/json" />
          <arg value="-X" />
          <arg value="PUT" />
          <arg value="-T" />
          <arg value="abc.json" />
          <arg value="https://myURL" />
      </exec>
  </target>
```